# adding specific dictionary values to emplty list in python

Tags: python, json, api, directory

when I query the api, I get a response  like this

(of course many other items):

{
"quick-nexo-eth": {
"vaultApr": 4.226980461491351,
"compoundingsPerYear": 2190,
"beefyPerformanceFee": 0.045,
"vaultApy": 67.23150416911541,
"lpFee": 0.003,
"tradingApr": 0.032865666659524465,
"totalApy": 69.47397804081551
},

"quick-qi-quick": {
"vaultApr": 244.9061731630718,
"compoundingsPerYear": 2190,
"beefyPerformanceFee": 0.045,
"vaultApy": 6.659993754798221e+100,
"lpFee": 0.003,
"tradingApr": 0.0919483717454164,
"totalApy": 7.27236933638656e+100
}
}

for each item, I would like to add the name (ie "quick-nexo-eth") and value of "totalApy" to a list so that I have a list that shows only name and totalapy, ie

my_list=[("quick-nexo-eth",69.47),("quick-qi-quick",7.27)]

some items in the list don't have the "totalApy" at all, so have to take that into consideration.
any help is apreciated. thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**:

```
api_response = {
    "quick-nexo-eth": {
        "vaultApr": 4.226980461491351,
        "compoundingsPerYear": 2190,
        "beefyPerformanceFee": 0.045,
        "vaultApy": 67.23150416911541,
        "lpFee": 0.003,
        "tradingApr": 0.032865666659524465,
        "totalApy": 69.47397804081551
    },
    "quick-qi-quick": {
        "vaultApr": 244.9061731630718,
        "compoundingsPerYear": 2190,
        "beefyPerformanceFee": 0.045,
        "vaultApy": 6.659993754798221e+100,
        "lpFee": 0.003,
        "tradingApr": 0.0919483717454164,
        "totalApy": 7.27236933638656e+100
    }
}

my_list = [(k, float(f'{v["totalApy"]:.4g}')) for k, v in api_response.items()
           if "totalApy" in v and v["totalApy"]]
print(my_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[('quick-nexo-eth', 69.47), ('quick-qi-quick', 7.272e+100)]
```

**Using actual API Response:**

```
import requests

beefy_api_url = "https://api.beefy.finance/apy/breakdown"
response = requests.get(beefy_api_url)
a_dict = response.json()
my_list = [(k, float(f'{v["totalApy"]:.4g}')) for k, v in a_dict.items()
           if "totalApy" in v and v["totalApy"]]
for coin, total_apy in my_list:
    print(coin, total_apy)
```

**Output:**

```
cometh-eth-wbtc 0.1167
cometh-eth-usdc 0.1843
cometh-must-pickle 0.2179
cometh-must-eth 1.249
cometh-eth-matic 0.2193
cometh-matic-must 0.8105
cometh-usdc-must 1.132
quick-ustw-matic 1.395
quick-gns-dai 0.08989
quick-mimatic-clam 50.9
quick-hbar[0x]-mimatic 0.7728
quick-tomb-mimatic 1.593
quick-matic-mana 0.4211
quick-matic-wcro 0.3807
quick-quick-erowan 1.285
quick-shib-matic 0.8575
quick-dpi-eth 1.531
quick-ftm-matic 0.4647
quick-watch-quick 28010000000000.0
quick-usdc-rbnb 0.5767
quick-qi-eth 8.365
quick-mai-usdt 0.1541
quick-dai-mai 0.1067
quick-mai-matic 1.231
quick-eth-rendoge 1.038
quick-usdc-quick 1.057
quick-pool-weth 11820.0
quick-wmatic-avax 0.1896
quick-sol-matic 0.2195
quick-uni-eth 0.442
quick-guard-usdc 3.843
quick-woo-eth 24.91
quick-quick-yamp 2.023e+136
quick-quick-polydoge 136.8
quick-yamp-usdc 4.88e+143
quick-nexo-eth 74.51
quick-qi-quick 8.919e+101
quick-polybunny-quick 5.441
quick-polybunny-eth 0.4921
quick-start-quick 0.5768
quick-eth-ramp 0.1672
quick-usdc-rusd 0.5031
quick-dai-usdt 0.07434
quick-usdc-dai 0.1046
quick-quick-uni 537100.0
quick-usdc-eth 0.1882
quick-dai-eth 0.2166
quick-btc-usdc 0.1175
quick-quick-eth 0.4996
quick-aave-eth 0.2007
quick-link-eth 0.1261
quick-eth-btc 0.07102
quick-eth-usdt 0.146
quick-usdc-usdt 0.07571
quick-quick 0.9463
quick-psp-matic 4.94
quick-kiro-matic 7.477
quick-usdt-matic 0.3185
quick-quick-matic 0.3531
quick-eth-matic 0.1578
quick-matic-usdc 0.3118
aave-matic 0.02858
aave-dai 0.04383
aave-usdc 0.04093
aave-eth 0.02439
aave-wbtc 0.007662
aave-aave 0.02004
aave-usdt 0.1025
sushi-bct-klima 5.882
sushi-usdc-bct 0.575
sushi-eth2x-eth 0.08969
sushi-fxs-frax 0.209
sushi-usdc-tusd 0.07509
sushi-axs-eth 0.1001
sushi-avax-weth 0.2031
sushi-wbtc-ibbtc 0.05826
sushi-usdc-bifi 0.09246
sushi-grt-eth 0.08474
sushi-usdc-dai 0.004702
sushi-crv-eth 0.04842
sushi-usdc-usdt 0.01135
sushi-link-eth 0.08687
sushi-aave-eth 0.04248
sushi-eth-dai 0.08403
sushi-btc-eth 0.02273
sushi-eth-usdt 0.1499
sushi-usdc-eth 0.04513
sushi-matic-eth 0.04814
sushi-wmatic-ghst 0.07647
sushi-jrt-eth 0.03616
sushi-fox-eth 0.1411
sushi-eth-gohm 0.9149
cometh-bifi-must 0.383
cometh-bifi-eth 0.1649
cometh-razor-eth 9.824
cometh-sdt-eth 1.387
cometh-doki-eth 798.2
cometh-azuki-eth 2.344
pzap-pzap-matic 0.9109
pzap-pzap-usdc 0.8518
polygon-bifi-maxi 0.1767
curve-am3crv 0.09621
curve-poly-ren 0.2872
curve-poly-atricrypto 0.08803
curve-poly-atricrypto2 0.02169
curve-poly-atricrypto3 0.3096
curve-poly-eurt 0.2011
ape-watch-matic 0.2467
ape-matic-usdt 0.3622
ape-matic-dai 0.3447
ape-eth-matic 0.1499
ape-btc-matic 0.1476
ape-bnb-matic 0.5376
ape-banana-matic 1.757
ape-usdc-dai 0.132
ape-wmatic-crystl 4.126
mai-qi-matic 3.101
mai-usdc-mimatic 0.2498
jetswap-poly-usdc-usdt 0.02274
jetswap-poly-pwings-usdt 0.0434
jetswap-poly-pwings-matic 1.999
jetswap-poly-pwings-usdc 0.03538
jetswap-poly-pwings 3.31
ironswap-3usd 0.04938
ironswap-iron 0.1382
ironswap-ice-iron 2.267
ironswap-ice-usdc 0.7867
ironswap-ice-eth 1.847
telxchange-quick-wmatic-tel 0.3057
telxchange-quick-aave-tel 0.5573
telxchange-quick-wbtc-tel 0.3614
farmhero-quick-usdc-honor 0.1087
farmhero-wault-usdc-honor 0.1685
dinoswap-dino-eth 0.1494
dinoswap-xmark-usdc 0.2881
dinoswap-dino-usdc 0.05503
dinoswap-usdc-usdt 0.04543
dinoswap-usdc-mimatic 0.01425
dinoswapv2-dino-usdc 3.281
dinoswapv2-dino-eth 5.234
polygonfarm-spade-usdc 5.933
polygonfarm-spade-matic 1.531
tetu-tetu-usdc 0.3804
tetu-matic-tetu 0.4127
sing-usdc-sing 1.349
cafe-pbrew-matic 4.319
cafe-pbrew-usdc 3.3
kyber-usdc-jeur 0.1629
kyber-usdc-jgbp 0.2106
kyber-usdc-jchf 0.1353
kyber-usdc-aur 0.8972
jarvis-2jpy 0.299
jarvis-5eur 0.2525
jarvis-4eur 0.2302
png-jewel-wavax 0.5797
png-dyp-wavax 4.633
png-teddy-wavax 0.2653
png-husky-wavax 0.1306
png-tusd-wavax 0.05007
png-ampl-wavax 0.711
png-wavax-frax 0.5819
png-qi-wavax 0.1724
png-wavax-xava 0.9395
png-roco-wavax 20.57
png-apein-wavax 0.007125
png-joe-wavax 1.053
png-walbt-wavax 0.1655
png-klo-wavax 0.3208
png-usdc.e-dai.e 0.07657
png-link.e-wavax 0.1515
png-usdc.e-wavax 0.4582
png-weth.e-wavax 0.1122
png-wavax-usdt.e 0.4422
png-wavax-dai.e 0.2686
png-wbtc.e-wavax 0.1923
png-wavax-time 93.43
png-wavax-spell 1.599
png-usdc.e-usdt.e 0.05392
png-png-usdc.e 0.7296
png-png-wavax 0.254
png-mim-usdc.e 0.2274
png-mim-wavax 1.637
lyd-lyd-avax 1.274
lyd-lyd-usdt 0.02934
png-png 0.301
olive-busd.e-usdt.e 0.0914
olive-dai.e-usdt.e 0.1717
olive-olive-usdt 0.08264
olive-olive-avax 3.439
avax-bifi-maxi 0.1589
joe-teddy-wavax 0.2721
joe-tsd-avax 0.09294
joe-joe-usdc.e 0.9373
joe-wavax-aave.e 0.5082
joe-weth.e-usdc.e 0.2426
joe-wbtc.e-usdc.e 0.1369
joe-wavax-bifi 0.136
joe-bnb-wavax 0.293
joe-usdc.e-usdt.e 0.2058
joe-frax-wavax 0.0169
joe-time-wavax 17.09
joe-mai-usdc.e 0.01666
joe-syn-wavax 0.913
joe-mim-wavax 0.8249
joe-qi-wavax 1.035
joe-usdc.e-dai.e 0.104
joe-usdc.e-wavax 0.4586
joe-shibx-wavax 0.2502
joe-wavax-dai.e 0.4536
joe-link.e-usdt.e 0.01859
joe-link.e-usdc.e 0.1629
joe-weth.e-usdt.e 0.01578
joe-wbtc.e-usdt.e 0.007927
joe-usdt.e-dai.e 0.09115
joe-joe-usdt.e 0.5663
joe-link.e-wavax 0.2323
joe-wavax-usdt.e 0.466
joe-wbtc.e-wavax 0.2176
joe-weth.e-wavax 0.2622
joe-yak-wavax 0.04245
joe-sherpa-wavax 0.1558
joe-wet-wavax 0.001763
joe-lyd-wavax 0.05877
joe-husky-wavax 0.1052
joe-wavax-elk 1.273
joe-vso-wavax 0.1603
joe-spore-wavax 0.06084
joe-wavax-pefi 0.08282
joe-wavax-snob 0.04783
joe-wavax-xava 0.4502
joe-png-wavax 0.7356
joe-usdc.e-usdc 0.2519
joe-ptp-wavax 344.8
joe-wavax-cly 2.445
joe-melt-wavax 2.078
joe-craft-wavax 7.3
joe-klo-wavax 1.459
joe-mead-wavax 0.07544
joe-awool-wavax 0.02623
joe-gohm-wavax 1.579
joe-cra-wavax 1.73
joe-wavax-boo 0.8121
joe-mai-wavax-v2 0.6997
joe-ampl-wavax 3.308
joe-joe-wavax 0.7386
joe-wavax-spell 0.6703
joe-joe 0.881
curve-avax-av3crv 0.1117
curve-avax-ren 0.06891
curve-avax-atricrypto 0.1443
aave-wavax 0.1176
aave-dai.e 0.08125
aave-usdc.e 0.0807
aave-usdt.e 0.03451
aave-weth.e 0.02633
aave-wbtc.e 0.009678
aave-aave.e 0.0542
sing-usdt.e-sing 2.284
blizz-blzz-avax 7.265
blizz-mim-supply 0.07627
blizz-mim 0.1434
blizz-avax-supply 0.0462
blizz-dai-supply 0.03777
blizz-usdt-supply 0.02672
blizz-usdc-supply 0.02073
blizz-eth-supply 0.01311
blizz-wbtc-supply 0.01381
blizz-avax 0.1639
blizz-dai 0.2121
blizz-usdt 0.1086
blizz-usdc 0.08247
blizz-eth 0.01311
blizz-wbtc 0.05279
bankerjoe-avax-supply 0.09649
bankerjoe-weth.e-supply 0.02373
bankerjoe-wbtc.e-supply 0.0216
bankerjoe-usdc.e-supply 0.07763
bankerjoe-usdt.e-supply 0.08074
bankerjoe-dai.e-supply 0.09146
bankerjoe-link.e-supply 0.01784
bankerjoe-mim-supply 0.5647
bankerjoe-avax 0.1286
bankerjoe-weth.e 0.02556
bankerjoe-wbtc.e 0.0216
bankerjoe-usdc.e 0.09333
bankerjoe-usdt.e 0.0822
bankerjoe-dai.e -0.05069
bankerjoe-link.e 0.01784
bankerjoe-mim 0.3618
synapse-nusdlp 0.1557
spell-avax-mim-crv 0.1584
mai-qi-wavax 1.795
mai-avax-mai-crv 0.189
boo-wftm-brush 2.464
boo-inv-wftm 2.379
boo-hnd-wftm 2.042
boo-wftm-matic 0.5767
boo-wftm-woo 0.7585
boo-wftm-avax 0.4348
boo-wftm-ooe 3.78
boo-wftm-wshec 1.05
boo-wftm-wsspa 1.643
boo-wftm-yoshi 0.2374
boo-usdc-tusd 0.1977
boo-wftm-joe 1.049
boo-usdc-mai 0.1704
boo-btc-eth 0.1419
boo-wftm-dola 1.304
boo-wftm-spell 1.117
boo-wftm-treeb 0.5234
boo-usdc-woo 0.1137
boo-wftm-shade 0.05149
boo-steak-wftm 0.3851
boo-wftm-foo 1.703
boo-ftm-scream 0.7074
boo-zoo-ftm 0.2187
boo-kek-ftm 0.8757
boo-yfi-eth 0.2963
boo-bifi-ftm 0.9405
boo-mim-ftm 1.113
boo-ftm-ice 0.9678
boo-ftm-badger 0.03604
boo-ftm-band 0.00492
boo-ftm-sushi 0.3228
boo-dai-ftm 0.7845
boo-any-ftm 0.9277
boo-woofy-ftm 0.04129
boo-bnb-ftm 0.6966
boo-link-ftm 0.2963
boo-cream-ftm 0.675
boo-snx-ftm 0.4127
boo-btc-ftm 0.4282
boo-usdt-ftm 0.6856
boo-crv-ftm 0.7076
boo-aave-ftm 0.2803
boo-eth-ftm 0.4902
boo-boo-ftm 0.5219
boo-ftm-usdc 0.9127
froyo-3pool 0.1533
froyo-froyo-ftm 0.1659
ester-est 0.4161
ester-est-ftm 1.468
boo-boo 0.5292
fantom-bifi-maxi 0.3072
tomb-tshare-ftm 7.751
tomb-tomb-ftm 2.176
spirit-yfi-ftm 0.1561
spirit-dai-usdc 0.2695
spirit-spell-sspell 0.1181
spirit-ftm-tarot 0.1465
spirit-any-ftm 0.4118
spirit-fusdt-ftm 0.7868
spirit-ftm-usdc 0.901
spirit-spirit-dai 0.2445
spirit-spirit-ftm 0.08323
spirit-zoo-ftm 0.04065
spirit-ftm-just 0.0344
spirit-ftm-sushi 0.1038
spirit-crv-ftm 0.178
spirit-link-ftm 0.0773
spirit-ftm-eth 0.2301
spirit-ftm-btc 0.1964
spirit-ftm-mim 0.9368
spirit-ftm-mai 0.9752
spirit-ftm-frax 0.7983
spirit-ftm-ice 0.674
spirit-ftm-wshec 0.9194
curve-ftm-tricrypto 0.252
curve-ftm-fusdt 0.02584
curve-ftm-2pool 0.07275
curve-ftm-ren 0.07556
curve-ftm-geist 0.1081
scream-usdc-supply 0.1821
scream-wbtc-supply 0.1512
scream-ftm-supply 0.02527
scream-dai-supply 0.1951
scream-eth-supply 0.1099
scream-fusdt-supply 0.1838
scream-frax-supply 0.2191
scream-mim-supply 0.1683
scream-dola-supply 0.2396
scream-tusd-supply 0.2611
scream-spell-supply 0.2074
scream-crv 0.4097
scream-link 0.1943
scream-usdc 0.1372
scream-wbtc 0.183
scream-ftm 0.07572
scream-dai 0.1868
scream-eth 0.1232
scream-fusdt 0.2031
scream-frax 0.3004
scream-mim 0.1693
scream-dola 0.581
scream-tusd 0.2438
scream-spell 0.4223
steakhouse-scream-ftm 7.417
stakesteak-fusd-usdc 35220.0
jetswap-fantom-fusdt-usdc 0.02126
jetswap-fantom-btc-usdc 0.05702
jetswap-fantom-eth-usdc 0.08693
jetswap-fantom-eth-btc 0.09406
jetswap-fantom-fwings-usdc 4.375
jetswap-fantom-fwings-ftm 3.296
jetswap-fantom-fwings 3.223
spell-ftm-mim-crv 0.08203
geist-geist-ftm 4.113
sing-ftm-usdc-sing 0.5915
pearzap-fpear-ftm 0.01012
pearzap-fpear-usdc 0.05187
beets-steady-beets-2 0.181
beets-dante-symphony 0.8655
beets-ode-to-joy 0.3349
beets-wagmi-index 5.782
beets-two-became-one 1.812
beets-variation-theme 0.1008
beets-battle-bands 1.449
beets-double-dollar-fugue 0.09584
beets-solana-sonata 0.942
beets-phantom-dai-opera 0.8902
beets-baron-von-binance 0.892
beets-symphony-nr-10 0.2449
beets-grand-orchestra 0.6584
beets-steady-beets 0.01584
beets-ftm-sonata 0.461
beets-e-major 0.2101
beets-b-major 0.1977
beets-classic-trio 0.324
beets-dance-of-degens 0.2517
beets-fantom-of-opera 0.8955
beets-ziggy-mim 0.2244
beets-guqin-qi 0.1514
beets-magic-touch-daniele 3.126
beets-sound-of-moosic 0.4228
beets-fantom-conservatory 1.101
beets-guqin-qi-2 0.1434
beets-late-quartet 0.6018
beets-song-ice-fire 1.501
beets-tubular-bells 1.235
summit-summit-ftm 12.44
summit-summit 1.195
geist-ftm-supply 0.02132
geist-fusdt-supply 0.03228
geist-dai-supply 0.02949
geist-usdc-supply 0.02595
geist-eth-supply 0.0051
geist-wbtc-supply 0.008528
geist-crv-supply 0.1729
geist-mim-supply 0.0764
geist-ftm 0.05529
geist-fusdt 0.1313
geist-dai 0.1119
geist-usdc 0.1073
geist-eth 0.06432
geist-wbtc 0.1135
geist-crv 0.4011
geist-mim 0.1728
geist-link 0.15
beets-fidelio-duetto 4.615
spartacadabra-charm-usdc 1.657
spartacadabra-lambda-crv 0.2819
popsicle-ice-ftm 1.013
2omb-2share-ftm 1234000000000.0
2omb-2omb-ftm 14890000000000.0
hfi-ht 0.0178
hfi-uni 0.0152
hfi-husd 0.0328
hfi-mdx 0.0304
hfi-aave 0.0045
hfi-usdt 0.0626
lava-lava 7.703e+84
hfi-hfi-ht 4.729
hfi-hfi-husd 0.641
mdex-shib-usdt 0.07414
mdex-bifi-usdt 0.1859
mdex-eth-wht 0.0325
mdex-uni-usdt 0.05573
mdex-yfi-usdt 0.1764
mdex-bal-usdt 0.3141
mdex-link-usdt 0.2743
mdex-snx-usdt 0.1436
mdex-aave-usdt 0.1028
mdex-lhb-usdt 0.3136
mdex-hpt-usdt 0.1279
mdex-hbtc-wht 0.05064
mdex-husd-usdt 0.01614
mdex-hltc-usdt 0.09624
mdex-hbch-usdt 0.2484
mdex-hdot-usdt 0.2058
mdex-hfil-usdt 0.1783
mdex-mdx-usdt 0.2727
mdex-mdx-wht 0.08455
mdex-wht-usdt 0.114
mdex-hbtc-usdt 0.08925
mdex-eth-usdt 0.1041
heco-bifi-maxi 0.03836
mdex-mdx 0.004375
lendhub-fil -0.04675
lendhub-dot 0.01886
lendhub-btc 0.01019
lendhub-eth 0.01751
lendhub-husd -0.07792
lendhub-lhb-wht 0.6888
lendhub-lhb-usdt 0.5473
alpaca-ibalpaca 0.07489
alpaca-ibbnb 0.1601
alpaca-ibbusd 0.06506
belt-beltbnb 0.2899
belt-beltbtc 0.03028
belt-belteth 0.02682
belt-4belt 0.05998
beltv2-4belt 0.05998
beltv2-belt-bnb 0.6391
bifi-maxi 0.1121
bifi-maxi-v2 0.1133
biswap-near-wbnb 0.4138
biswap-avax-wbnb 0.2775
biswap-sol-wbnb 0.1285
biswap-wbnb-matic 0.2745
biswap-ftm-wbnb 0.3045
biswap-shib-wbnb 0.2033
biswap-axs-wbnb 0.4526
biswap-wbnb-bifi 0.3881
biswap-eth-sushi 0.1601
biswap-bsw-bfg 1.224
biswap-trx-wbnb 0.3936
biswap-twt-wbnb 0.2945
biswap-wbnb-xvs 0.5004
biswap-fil-usdt 0.1701
biswap-wbnb-bake 0.2691
biswap-wbnb-link 0.1478
biswap-doge-wbnb 0.1112
biswap-xrp-wbnb 0.4997
biswap-vai-busd 0.05234
biswap-ltc-usdt 0.1315
biswap-ust-busd 0.09091
biswap-tusd-busd 0.1045
biswap-ada-wbnb 0.139
biswap-wbnb-uni 0.1793
biswap-dot-wbnb 0.2129
biswap-dai-usdt 0.05904
biswap-eth-wbnb 0.1101
biswap-cake-wbnb 0.6179
biswap-bsw-wbnb 1.077
biswap-usdt-bsw 0.9924
biswap-btcb-wbnb 0.1868
biswap-eth-btcb 0.05802
biswap-usdt-btcb 0.06819
biswap-eth-usdt 0.1015
biswap-usdt-usdc 0.07714
biswap-wbnb-busd 0.3058
biswap-usdt-wbnb 0.4113
biswap-usdt-busd 0.03825
biswap-biswap 0.8072
cake-cake 0.6022
cake-smart 0.6022
cakev2-insur-wbnb 1.456
cakev2-wbnb-gm 6.709
cakev2-woop-wbnb 1.116
cakev2-high-busd 1.038
cakev2-ccar-wbnb 4.298
cakev2-wbnb-dpt 5.364
cakev2-thg-wbnb 0.7052
cakev2-xcv-busd 5.292
cakev2-idia-busd 1.726
cakev2-nabox-busd 0.475
cakev2-santos-wbnb 2.346
cakev2-quidd-wbnb 4.144
cakev2-zoo-wbnb 1.514
cakev2-qi-wbnb 1.305
cakev2-kart-wbnb 6.498
cakev2-porto-wbnb 1.861
cakev2-wbnb-eternal 3.294
cakev2-xwg-usdc 0.519
cakev2-dar-wbnb 0.7564
cakev2-dkt-wbnb 0.4165
cakev2-lazio-wbnb 0.2944
cakev2-rpg-busd 0.1824
cakev2-wbnb-beta 0.5511
cakev2-nft-wbnb 0.06071
cakev2-sfund-wbnb 1.549
cakev2-bp-wbnb 1.376
cakev2-rusd-busd 0.04255
cakev2-btt-busd 0.06241
cakev2-trx-busd 0.0781
cakev2-win-busd 0.0272
cakev2-bmon-wbnb 0.3501
cakev2-sps-wbnb 0.2959
cakev2-c98-wbnb 0.458
cakev2-axs-wbnb 0.3536
cakev2-chess-usdc 0.614
cakev2-one-wbnb 0.04833
cakev2-mask-wbnb 0.3065
cakev2-dvi-wbnb 0.1303
cakev2-usdt-usdc 0.04518
cakev2-cake-usdt 0.3703
cakev2-bscpad-wbnb 0.05848
cakev2-woo-bnb 0.1182
cakev2-o3-busd 0.7353
cakev2-btcb-eth 0.03728
cakev2-eth-usdc 0.07754
cakev2-mbox-bnb 0.02146
cakev2-tusd-busd 0.0412
cakev2-chr-busd 0.3075
cakev2-cake-busd 0.296
cakev2-doge-bnb 0.2823
cakev2-btcb-busd 0.07367
cakev2-hotcross-bnb 0.07244
cakev2-alpaca-busd 0.1907
cakev2-xrp-bnb 0.1981
cakev2-uni-bnb 0.1476
cakev2-sxp-bnb 0.147
cakev2-eps-bnb 0.2685
cakev2-ust-busd 0.01691
cakev2-bunny-bnb 0.1654
cakev2-tko-bnb 0.09767
cakev2-tlm-bnb 0.1307
cakev2-itam-bnb 0.2249
cakev2-bifi-bnb 0.1674
cakev2-alice-bnb 0.1572
cakev2-belt-bnb 0.2137
cakev2-ramp-busd 0.1062
cakev2-iotx-busd 0.09277
cakev2-lina-busd 0.08598
cakev2-usdc-busd 0.02116
cakev2-dai-busd 0.01355
cakev2-sushi-eth 0.1147
cakev2-dodo-bnb 0.1227
cakev2-sfp-bnb 0.07358
cakev2-btcst-bnb 0.1877
cakev2-ltc-bnb 0.09901
cakev2-ada-bnb 0.08221
cakev2-dot-bnb 0.1192
cakev2-vai-busd 0.03215
cakev2-alpha-bnb 0.1744
cakev2-inj-bnb 0.2008
cakev2-twt-bnb 0.09709
cakev2-xvs-bnb 0.2515
cakev2-usdt-busd 0.02207
cakev2-btcb-bnb 0.1065
cakev2-usdt-bnb 0.09239
cakev2-eth-bnb 0.0837
cakev2-link-bnb 0.09258
cakev2-cake-bnb 0.456
cakev2-busd-bnb 0.07941
cake-cakev2 0.6429
ramen-ramen-bnb 1.41
ramen-ramen-busd 1.653
blizzard-xblzd 1.159
blizzard-xblzd-busd 1.824
salt-salt-busd 1.494
salt-salt-bnb 0.8539
banana-crush-wbnb 0.5558
banana-frax-busd 0.2807
banana-wbnb-fxs 0.6924
banana-oasis-wbnb 1.804
banana-exp-wbnb 0.1131
banana-tusd-busd 0.01236
banana-fil-wbnb 0.5991
banana-wbnb-dep 0.6582
banana-wbnb-ceek 0.9587
banana-nfty-wbnb 1.793
banana-ong-bnb 0.3328
banana-bhc-bnb 0.07739
banana-caps-bnb 0.01817
banana-hotcross-busd 0.07792
banana-busd-bnb 0.3347
banana-eth-bnb 0.2853
banana-sxp-bnb 0.2929
banana-bake-bnb 0.01064
banana-cake-bnb 0.7328
banana-btcb-bnb 0.2265
banana-cyt-bnb 0.7357
banana-land-bnb 0.6342
banana-guard-bnb 0.7203
banana-pots-bnb 0.4577
banana-tape-bnb 0.01435
banana-bnb-sista 4.29
banana-axs-bnb 0.5587
banana-fruit-bnb 8.374e-05
banana-bnb-stars 1.462
banana-yfi-bnb 0.4638
banana-twt-bnb 0.3927
banana-xvs-bnb 0.1644
banana-eps-bnb 0.3347
banana-sfp-bnb 0.4428
banana-ata-bnb 0.01659
banana-typh-bnb 0.006536
banana-celr-bnb 0.3823
banana-shib-bnb 0.3809
banana-sushi-bnb 0.6453
banana-dot-bnb 0.2196
banana-xrp-bnb 0.2068
banana-blz-bnb 0.01912
banana-snx-bnb 0.2669
banana-ltc-bnb 0.17
banana-near-bnb 0.7793
banana-coti-bnb 0.8133
banana-etc-bnb 0.0082
banana-zec-bnb 0.4168
banana-avax-bnb 0.4121
banana-ftm-bnb 0.2815
banana-comp-bnb 0.1762
banana-aave-bnb 0.2615
banana-link-bnb 0.2456
banana-ada-bnb 0.3119
banana-matic-bnb 0.3231
banana-watch-bnb 0.2711
banana-naut-bnb 0.8459
banana-bxbtc-bnb 0.00297
banana-busd-usdc 0.06289
banana-doge-bnb 0.2927
banana-ont-bnb 0.2149
banana-keyfi-bnb 0.07345
banana-ada-eth 0.2661
banana-iota-bnb 0.4718
banana-bat-bnb 0.3142
banana-bifi-bnb 0.3046
banana-banana-bnb 1.424
banana-banana-busd 1.161
banana-banana 1.054
banana-bananav2 1.062
space-space-busd 1.249
space-space-bnb 0.6521
zefiv2-zefi-bnb 1.034
zefiv2-zefi-busd 0.6485
swampv2-swamp-bnb 1.188
swampv2-swamp-busd 0.5914
swamp-swamp 1.182
goal-goal-busd 0.716
panther-panther-bnb 4.385
panther-panther-busd 7.101
kingdefi-krown-bnb 1.815
pera-pera-bnb 3.244
auro-auro-bnb 3.296
auro-auro-busd 6.233
long-long-wbnb 0.1569
czf-czf-busd 24.12
czf-czf-bnb 24.11
annex-ann-busd 1.343
annex-ann 0.9496
pacoca-pacoca-bnb 4.353
pacoca-pacoca 2.668
sing-sing-busd 0.7069
cafev2-brew-bnb 0.9249
cafev2-brew-busd 1.34
baby-aot-usdt 0.366
baby-usdt-milk 3.404
baby-baby-bnb 2.971
baby-baby-usdt 2.212
baby-baby 0.838
wsg-wsg-bnb 1.725
wsg-wsg 0.8079
nfty-nfty 0.9283
betu-betu 0.1905
bison-bison-bnb 3.384
bison-bison 1.193
blockmine-nugget-goldcoin 7.584
charge-static-busd 19.15
charge-charge-busd 39.29
dibs-dshare-bnb 145900.0
dibs-dibs-bnb 88820.0
ellipsis-usdn 0.04412
ellipsis-pbtc 0.03575
ellipsis-renbtc 0.03645
ellipsis-fusdt-3eps 0.03429
ellipsis-3eps 0.0345
ellipsis-eps-bnb 0.3768
ellipsis-eps 0.02646
farmhero-pancake-hero-wbnb 0.2171
farmhero-pancake-hero-busd 0.1079
ica-zeth 1.002
ica-zbtc 0.005884
jetswap-btcb-bnb 0.1632
jetswap-usdc-busd 0.01896
jetswap-busd-bnb 0.08614
jetswap-wings-bnb 0.8777
jetswap-wings-busd 1.354
jetswap-fuel-bnb 0.01817
jetswap-fts-bnb 0.3384
jetswap-wings 0.7676
kebab-eth-btcb 0.07819
kebab-kebab-btc 6.1
kebab-bifi-busd 0.06002
kebab-kebab-busd 1.325
kebab-kebab-bnb 0.9054
kebab-kebab 0.7588
mdex-lac-busd 0.2678
mdex-usdt-btcb 0.1151
mdex-bsc-usdt-usdc 0.01141
mdex-bsc-usdt-busd 0.007705
mdex-rabbit-busd 0.07195
mdex-bsc-bnb-usdt 0.0573
mdex-bsc-fil-usdt 0.1253
mdex-bsc-bifi-usdt 0.1551
mdex-bsc-busd-bnb 0.2483
mdex-bsc-btc-usdt 0.1151
mdex-bsc-eth-usdt 0.1314
mdex-bsc-eth-btc 0.0523
mdex-bsc-mdx-bnb 0.06749
mdex-bsc-mdx-busd 0.2759
mdex-bsc-mdx 0.004206
omnifarm-usdo-busd-ot 0.08401
omnifarm-usdo-bdp 1.773
omnifarm-usdo-popen 0.4057
omnifarm-usdo-anymtlx 0.6128
omnifarm-fet-usdo 0.5972
omnifarm-ocp-usdo 0.5245
omnifarm-usdo-wbnb 0.268
ooe-ooe-bnb 1.919
ooe-ooe-busd 1.542
pots-pots 0.6579
pots-watch 0.4122
tenfi-tenfi-busd 1.468
tenfi-tenfi-bnb 1.58
venus-ada 0.02115
venus-beth 0.04516
venus-dai 0.04114
venus-fil 0.04151
venus-bch 0.03249
venus-dot -0.001526
venus-link 0.04587
venus-sxp 0.03191
venus-usdc 0.05654
venus-usdt 0.01772
venus-busd 0.02383
venus-bnb 0.1634
venus-xvs -0.0006551
venus-btcb 0.01656
venus-eth 0.004472
venus-ltc 0.02871
venus-xrp 0.01448
venus-wbnb 0.1634
yel-yel-wbnb 6.83
yel-yel 0.1458
sushi-one-bifi-wone 0.6124
sushi-one-wone-1btc 1.045
sushi-one-1ygg-1eth 0.5693
sushi-one-1eth-1aave 0.2788
sushi-one-1axs-1eth 0.7853
sushi-one-1eth-1dai 0.1213
sushi-one-1usdt-1eth 0.1627
sushi-one-1eth-1frax 0.8787
sushi-one-ust-1eth 0.2998
sushi-one-1wbtc-1eth 0.1131
sushi-one-1usdt-1usdc 0.07682
sushi-one-1usdt-wone 0.04935
sushi-one-busd-one 0.1954
sushi-one-bscbusd-busd 0.08438
sushi-one-eth-one 0.2054
sushi-one-btc-one 0.1332
sushi-one-sushi-one 0.09121
sushi-one-usdc-one 0.1017
curve-harmony-3pool 0.1119
curve-harmony-tricrypto 0.3672
one-bifi-maxi 0.05407
sushi-arb-weth-usdt 0.2339
sushi-arb-wbtc-weth 0.02956
sushi-arb-weth-link 0.08904
sushi-arb-sushi-eth 0.1602
sushi-arb-eth-usdc 0.3188
arbinyan-nyan-eth 17880000000.0
arbinyan-nyan 6353.0
curve-arb-tricrypto 0.2295
curve-arb-2pool 0.0908
curve-arb-ren 0.0613
curve-arb-eurs 0.161
sushi-arb-magic-weth 3.493
sushi-arb-weth-gohm 0.7377
sushi-arb-weth-mim 0.2756
sushi-arb-spell-weth 0.4885
spell-mim-crv 0.1041
arbi-bifi-maxi 0.1754
sushi-celo-celo-mobi 2.848
sushi-celo-weth-usdt 0.2813
sushi-celo-cusd-usdc 0.2252
sushi-celo-weth-daiv2 0.2831
sushi-celo-cusd-ceurv2 0.2114
sushi-celo-wethv2-cusd 0.5136
sushi-celo-wethv2-celo 0.585
celo-bifi-maxi 0.2314
solarbeam-frax-wmovr 0.1864
solarbeam-pets-wmovr 3.355
solarbeam-mim-usdc 0.09836
solarbeam-wmovr-ftm 0.6692
solarbeam-mimatic-usdc 0.002712
solarbeam-wmovr-relay 0.4124
solarbeam-avax-wmovr 0.4058
solarbeam-matic-wmovr 0.3284
solarbeam-usdt-usdc 0.09778
solarbeam-wbtc-usdc 0.2218
solarbeam-bnb-busd 0.4671
solarbeam-eth-usdc 0.2697
solarbeam-busd-usdc 0.1434
solarbeam-dai-usdc 0.09655
solarbeam-wmovr-usdc 0.9689
solarbeam-wmovr-rib 1.132
solarbeam-solar-rib 0.05806
solarbeam-solar-wmovr 4.252
solarbeam-solar-usdc 2.626
solarbeam-wbtc-wmovr 0.3557
solarbeam-eth-wmovr 0.9357
solarbeam-bnb-wmovr 0.6857
solarbeam-mim-wmovr 1.049
solarbeam-frax-wmovr-2 1.452
solarbeam-wmovr-mai 1.227
solarbeam-frax-rome 2.402
sushi-mr-mim-wmovr 0.5576
sushi-mr-frax-usdc 0.08538
sushi-mr-eth-wmovr 0.6046
sushi-mr-usdt-usdc 0.09576
sushi-mr-eth-usdt 0.1807
sushi-mr-eth-bnb 0.2648
sushi-mr-eth-wbtc 0.1007
sushi-mr-eth-dai 0.2542
movr-bifi-maxi 0.2153
finn-finn-bnb 2.809
finn-finn-ftm 2.385
finn-finn-doge 0.00134
finn-wan-finn 0.03609
finn-eth-finn 4.067
finn-wbtc-finn 0.02463
finn-finn-usdt 9.952
finn-finn-avax 4.289
finn-finn-xrp 1.566
finn-usdc-usdt 0.1722
finn-wbtc-wmovr 0.7164
finn-eth-wmovr 0.7034
finn-wan-wmovr 0.9333
finn-wmovr-usdt 1.391
finn-dot-finn 2.478
finn-usdc-finn 7.533
finn-wmovr-finn 4.764
finn-finn 2.456
vvs-tonic-usdc 1.263
vvs-tonic-cro 1.246
vvs-cro-atom 0.7835
vvs-cro-doge 0.2335
vvs-cro-bifi 0.7764
vvs-cro-dai 0.4159
vvs-cro-usdt 0.3907
vvs-cro-usdc 0.3423
vvs-cro-shib 0.1489
vvs-vvs-usdt 4.49
vvs-usdt-usdc 0.09753
vvs-cro-btc 0.5146
vvs-cro-eth 0.5104
vvs-vvs-cro 2.023
vvs-vvs-usdc 3.395
vvs-vvs 1.363
crona-wbtc-eth 0.2478
crona-usdc-eth 0.3579
crona-wbtc-usdc 0.2386
crona-usdc-dai 0.1718
crona-usdt-crona 5.081
crona-crona-usdc 5.56
crona-busd-bnb 0.344
crona-usdt-usdc 0.1281
crona-usdt-ftm 0.9546
crona-usdt-busd 0.1353
crona-wbtc-cro 0.1038
crona-cro-usdt 0.4253
crona-cro-usdc 0.4868
crona-cro-crona 4.917
crona-crona 3.144
cronos-bifi-maxi 0.09131
liq-liq-cro 3.599
trisolaris-near-tri 3.991
trisolaris-near-wbtc 0.8296
trisolaris-usdt-usdc 0.1779
trisolaris-usdt-near 1.012
trisolaris-usdc-near 0.8814
trisolaris-near-weth 0.7268
fusefi-wfuse-g$ 6.949
fusefi-wfuse-busd 5.064
fusefi-fusd-bnb 2.267
fusefi-wfuse-fusd 4.065
fusefi-wbtc-weth 0.7195
fusefi-wfuse-weth 1.916
fusefi-wfuse-usdc 2.872
fuse-fuse 0.2157
netswap-m.usdt-m.usdc 0.3478
netswap-weth-m.usdc 0.841
netswap-weth-m.usdt 0.7773
netswap-metis-m.usdc 7.607
netswap-m.usdt-metis 8.425
netswap-weth-metis 6.569
netswap-bnb-nett 71480.0
netswap-weth-nett 23340.0
netswap-nett-metis 358.0
netswap-nett-m.usdc 7117.0
netswap-nett-m.usdt 6692.0
```

Comment: thanks! that seem to work, but when I put the actual api request it gives me an error

beefy_api_url="https://api.beefy.finance/apy/breakdown/"

#query the api and  extract a json data from the response
response = requests.get(beefy_api_url)
a_dict = response.json()


my_list = [(k, float(f'{v["totalApy"]:.4g}')) for k, v in a_dict.items()
           if "totalApy" in v]
print(my_list)


>>the error it says:

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__

could it be because of some items value is maybe not consistent? maybe missing or a string?

Comment: Fixed, see above. Consider adding information as you provided in your comment to the actual question in the future. Similarly, for faster responses and from more people try utilizing the markdown formatting features in your questions.

Comment: done! sorry, this was my first post in here.